# insert -> Senseless!

Tags: lyx

Working with LyX, I opened the Insert menu in order to insert a label. Accidentally, my mouse selected something else, I don't know what, and before I knew it, I saw the phrase "Senseless!!!" in the middle of the page.

I tried to look at the Insert menu to find out what could generate such phrase. I looked for "Insert -> Criticism" or "Insert -> Content Analysis" or "Insert -> What the reviewers are going to say about your paper", but haven't found anything like this.

What makes LyX say "Senseless!!!"???

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=lyx+senseless&oq=lyx+senseless&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.2179j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8) suggests you tried to insert a caption outside of a float.  But without more information it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens when you try and insert a caption in the main document outside a float:

[image]

The output makes *sense*, albeit somewhat harsh and unhelpful, since there's no information to caption. Typically, captions have some environment reference and numbering in order to use a label and reference.

While doing this does not produce an error *per se*, it will once you compile the input, since `\caption` cannot be used outside a float (without help). This is what you'll see as an error:

[image]